# Add buttons in a datagridview field of winform

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, devexpress

I am using Dexexpress xtragrid column and have displayed all rows of my database.

I wanted to add a new column to the datagridview and for that i did the following:

```
Dim AddOperationsColumn As New GridColumn()
AddOperationsColumn.Name = "colOperations"
AddOperationsColumn.FieldName = "Operations"
AddOperationsColumn.Caption = "Operations"
Grid_view_patients.Columns.Insert(1, AddOperationsColumn)
AddOperationsColumn.Visible = True
AddOperationsColumn.VisibleIndex = TotalColumns + 1
```

**Now i want to add two buttons to it** `Edit` and `Delete`

Question: So how to add buttons to these fields.

I have already counted all the rows.

Comment: What do you mean adding two buttons to the fields? Do you mean RepositoryItem ?

Comment: @DTs Yes through RepositoryItem, but i don't know how exactly i can use it.

Comment: Adding repository item to a column means that the button will be on every row in the grid. Are you sure do you want to achieve that? If you want to add functionality for editing and inserting entire rows from the grid, you should consider using the DataNavigator

Comment: Please tell what exactly you want to achieve and I'll try to provide you with an example

Comment: @DTs yes i want to edit each and every row. But i has to be like, when i click delete i will execute the code for deleting that particular row only. So my motto is on howto add button to it first.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

Using the [DataNavigator](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDataNavigatortopic)
is pretty straightforward. Just set the Grid property UseEmbebedNavigator to true and it'll show in the bottom of the grid.

In order to provide own functionality for the button pressed, you need to handle the [NavigatorBase.ButtonClick Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsNavigatorBase_ButtonClicktopic)

For example:

```
private void gridControl_EmbeddedNavigator_ButtonClick(object sender, NavigatorButtonClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button.ButtonType == NavigatorButtonType.Remove)
        {
            //getting the selected object
            myObject selectedItem = dbGridView.GetRow(dbGridView.FocusedRowHandle) as myObejct;
            if (selectedItem == null) return;

            //now do something with that object
            .......

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

*Please note that the above code overrides the DataNavigator's default behavior*

**Solution 2**

Another way is to edit the grid rows in place. For this your datasource needs to be BindingList. You can see the template DevExpress WinForms project.

Comment: But how i can add the buttons pragmatically?

Comment: Why don't you use the designer ? The buttons are automatically included in the DataNavigator. You can reach them by Grid.EmbeddedNavigator.Buttons

Comment: Because i have dynamic data. Its get generated with some combination of queries depending on some dynamic values.

Comment: Also, how exactly i can show these 2 buttons in the `colOperations` column fields?

Comment: Ok, you want to use repository items, not the data navigator. Please note that only one repository item (in your case button) can be included in one column. In that case, you need two columns in the grid for the two buttons

Comment: ok, what exactly do i need to program to show that buttons in that column. Lets say i have added `Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository` but now what exactly i need to provide to get my button there?

Answer (score 1):

**Using repository items**

```
    RepositoryItemButtonEdit editButton;
    RepositoryItemButtonEdit deleteButton;

    private void InitRepositoryItems()
    {
        editButton = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
        deleteButton = new RepositoryItemButtonEdit();


        editButton.ButtonClick += editButton_ButtonClick;
        deleteButton.ButtonClick += deleteButton_ButtonClick;

        gridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(editButton);
        gridControl.RepositoryItems.Add(deleteButton);

    }

    void deleteButton_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do some delete on button click
    }

    void editButton_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
       //do some edit on button click
    } 

    private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "colOperations")
            e.RepositoryItem = editButton;
    }
```

the `gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit` is used to assign the RepositoryItem in the corresponding column (in our case the column colOperations)

Comment: I must say you really have great command on programming. 

Anyways, but will this show the command button in the fields of `colOperations` As currently its not showing.

Comment: Yes, as long as you call the InitRepositoryItems() from the Loading event of the form or in the constructor.

Comment: I did the same, but i am sure this will work but maybe i am unable to catch the concept:

is it should like this 

`Dim AddOperationsColumn As New GridColumn()
                AddOperationsColumn.Name = "colOperations"
                AddOperationsColumn.FieldName = "Operations"
                AddOperationsColumn.Caption = "Operations"
                Grid_view_patients.Columns.Insert(1, AddOperationsColumn)
                AddOperationsColumn.Visible = True
                AddOperationsColumn.VisibleIndex = TotalColumns + 1` 

                `InitRepositoryItems()`

Comment: What is `gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit`